# SQL Where Statement Removing Contracts with 2nd "-"

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, where-clause, remove-if

I've got a table with a list of contracts:

CT-12345, CT-12346, CT-12347, CT-12347-B1, CT-12560-A1, etc. etc.

I need a where statement where it'll exclude anything that has a -... at the end of the contract. A '%-%' would exclude the first 3 as well but in my final output, from the above example, CT-12347-B1 and CT-12560-A1 would be excluded while CT-12345, CT-12346, CT-12347 would be included. I'm using SQL Server R2. Thoughts?

Thanks,

Joshua

Comment: Essentially you seem to be looking to exclude those containing 2 `-`'s, is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
WHERE contract NOT LIKE '%-%-%'
```